# Why are my CSS transitions not working when adding classes through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm making a website and the transition is not working how it's suppose to. also, 7.css doesn't interfere because it's the same issue without it and also the transition works when using window:hover.

I tried to add a class through jQuery, and what *should* happen is it should apply the css transition on the window class. however, it does not work and adds the class but does not do the transition.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/7.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vertical"></div>
    <div id=info1>
    <div class="window active glass center400" style="max-width:400px;">
      <div class="title-bar">
        <div class="title-bar-text">Info</div>
        <div class="title-bar-controls">
          <button aria-label="Minimize" disabled></button>
          <button aria-label="Maximize" disabled></button>
          <button aria-label="Close" class=closewindow data-parentid=info1 onclick=closeinfo()></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="window-body has-space">
        <h4>donkeys are pretty cool</h4><br><br>
        i love donkeys.
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: url(img0.jpg) center center fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
      .window {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        transform: perspective(0), rotateZ(0);
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: 200ms ease all, 300ms ease opacity;
        -moz-transition: 200ms ease all, 300ms ease opacity;
        -ms-transition: 200ms ease all, 300ms ease opacity;
        transition: 200ms ease all, 300ms ease opacity;
      }
      .window-body {
        -webkit-user-select: default;
        -ms-user-select: default;
        user-select: default;
      }
      div.vertical {
        display: none;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 1000 !important;
        background: red;
      }
      
      @media only screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 6/5) {
        div.vertical {
          display: block;
        }
      }
      h4 {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .center400 {
        left: calc(50vw - 200px);
        top: 35vh;
      }
      [role=button],button{
          transition: 100ms;
      }
      .close {
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform: perspective(1500px) rotateX(10deg) translateY(-10px);
        opacity: 0;
      }
```

jQuery:

```js
     function closeinfo() {
        $("#info1").addClass("close");
      }
      $(".window").draggable({
        handle: ".title-bar"
      });
```

fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aysk4tcv/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i just needed to get rid of the wrapper div and put #info on the window div.